# Change the form-edit-account.php template in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, account

I want to do in form-edit-account.php in woocommerce, there were fields for reading, but when clicking on the button, the user will be able to edit his data, what is the best way to implement it? the code itself is here:

```
<?php
    
/**
 * Edit account form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' ); ?> >

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="account_last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_display_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Display name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?>" /> <span><em><?php esc_html_e( 'This will be how your name will be displayed in the account section and in reviews', 'woocommerce' ); ?></em></span>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php esc_html_e( 'Password change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_current"><?php esc_html_e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_1"><?php esc_html_e( 'New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_2"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
        <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has a help document on how to override templates:

> Edit files in an upgrade-safe way using overrides. Copy the template into a directory within your theme named `/woocommerce` keeping the same file structure but removing the `/templates/` subdirectory.

Source:
https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#how-to-edit-files